# Matching inner code regardless of any wrapping text

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string like:

```
[code]var foo = {
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
};[/code]
```

I can use `/^(?:\[code\])?([\s\S]*?)(?:\[\/code\])?$/i` to get the inner text (between the `[code]` and `[/code]`) regardless if it is surrounded with the code tags.

What I'd like to do is to allow the beginning and end tags to be a little more fuzzy. I'm getting this text by user selection of the inner code and therefor the selection may not be perfect, the selection may be into the code tags. The selection may be something like:

```
ode]var foo = {
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
};[/co
```

but I still only want the inner code. What's the best way to match the code tags in a way that it'll match even if not all there?

Comment: Why you don't get the code between `]` and `[`?

Comment: What characters can you guarantee to be always present?

Comment: The answer below is a great solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just the brackets instead the full tag, like this:

```
\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC4rW7/1)**

Comment: @MitchellSimoens btw, you can also use `(?s)\](.*?)\[\/`